# Confusion on preposition following “report”

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing a passage titled "Report [] Projects for sth." I'm not sure which preposition I shall use. "on" vs "about" vs "of"? What are differences.

Moreover, it seems readily for me to get confused with this structure "noun. + prep. + none." Is there a good method to distinguish them? How can I get familiar with these? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to actually use the word "Projects"? Or is it a placeholder for some specific project name?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, projects each with several tasks.

Comment: As far as I know (I'm a non-native speaker too), there is no specific rule for [n1.+prep.+n2.]; it's most likely to be influenced by either [n1.] or [n2.].

Comment: I believe that you might probably want to write *A Report on X, Y, and Z, for P*. If I have to choose the preposition in this specific usage, *on* is probably the best choice (I don't know what are those X, Y, and Z), then *of*, and then *about*. Hope this helps. Also, wait for a few more hours, there are many native speakers around here that can sort this issue out for you.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for the word "report", I'd use the following prepositions... (I'm assuming that the examples are the titles of the reports, so I'm using title case.)

> **Report on Air Pollution** [report is about air pollution]
>
> **Report of/by My Research Group** [report is written *by* my research group]
>
> **Report to/for the Environmental Protection Agency** [report is written *for* the EPA]

These prepositions can of course be combined:

> **Report on Air Pollution for the EPA by My Research Group**

The question of when to use prepositions in general is too broad to cover in this site's Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

You can report **to** someone (often your direct boss), and you can hear a report **of** some event or other.

A report can be **about** or (more usually and more formally) **on** something.

You can write a report **for** some client publication, employer or interested body.

On your specific question on the 'on' vs 'of', the most usual use of 'of' is with the noun form of 'report': "several reports have been coming in of disturbances on Clare Street." If you want to express a similar a similar meaning using the verb form of 'report', treat it as transitive verb ("the police report disturbances on Clare Street") or use a subordinate clause ("the researchers have reported that the new antibiotic is effective against Streptococcus resistant to penicilin.")

To report *on* an event often means to provide further information about an already identified event:

"The police had brought the violence under control by 2:30 this morning; Christina Aguirre is on the ground to report on the aftermath. ... Over to you, Christina."

To tell someone that a report deals with a particular subject, just use 'on':
"The research team have just published a report on the effectiveness of the new antibiotic."

I should mention that 'of' can also be a synonym for 'by' or 'written by':
"The second report of the Commission on Safety in the Workplace."